# Gerrit configuration

Tags: gerrit

we want to use gerrit for code reviews but we are missing some settings in the webview.

- is it possible to forbid committers to review/verify their own
  commits?
- is it possible that two reviewers give +1 an accumulate it
  to a +2 so it can be submitted?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - is it possible to forbid committers to review/verify their own commits?

Yes, setup autobuild to verify all commits. You can set this up by using the [Gerrit Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) for Jenkins or [gReview](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.houghtonassociates.bamboo.plugins.gReview/server/installation) for Bamboo. That way nobody has to verify commits. Additionally, you can setup superusers so only a select group can actually merge the final reviewed change.

> is it possible that two reviewers give +1 an accumulate it to a +2 so
>   it can be submitted?

No, two +1 doesn't make the +2 necessary to submit. Here's what the [doc](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html) says:

> The label that the reviewer selects determines what can happen next.
>   The +1 and -1 level are just an opinion where as the +2 and -2 levels
>   are allowing or blocking the change. In order for a change to be
>   accepted it must have at least one +2 and no -2 votes. Although these
>   are numeric values, they in no way accumulate; two +1s do not equate
>   to a +2.

Comment: hi thanks for crawling the docs, an is it possible to require two +2's ? or is the voting system static?

Comment: np, I actually didn't have to crawl the doc for that part. I've gone through the voting thoroughly. The voting system is pretty static. However, you can add additional rules as part of the review in scripts. I haven't tried it so I can offer much detail on that: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_rules_a_section_rules . I'm not sure if you can make such adjustments from this configuration option or not. Might be worth asking in the google groups for Gerrit.

Answer (score 5):

You can forbid self-reviews and add a +1 + +1 = +2 rule, but it isn't well documented.  Newer versions of Gerrit use a prolog engine to calculate submit rules.  Improved documentation for this feature is actually being worked on currently: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/c/37102/

Answer (score 0):

The documentation that Brad mentioned in his answer is now merged into the master branch of Gerrit and available in the latest release (2.5.1 as of now):

[Make change submittable only if Code-Review+2 is given by a non author](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#NonAuthorCodeReview)

[Make two +1 votes equal +2](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#_example_13_1_1_2_code_review)